# Retrieving value from Python SimpleCookie and using it in SELECT query

Tags: python, cookies, cgi

I posted a question yesterday :
[Redirect python script to another python script for validation of login credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294473/redirect-python-script-to-another-python-script-for-validation-of-login-credenti)

after i was done with that bit, i had another problem related to cookies. I sent the cookies in the header from the python script code:

```
        #Create Cookie
        C= Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        #take the value of usernameLogin into the variable username
        username= form.getvalue('usernameLogin')
        #Set-Cookie header with the usernameLogin key
        C['usernameLogin'] = username
```

this code is in the previous python script **validate.py**

i want to send the cookies to the next script **page1.py**
this is my code for **page1.py** :

```
import cgi
import cgitb
import sqlite3
import Cookie
import os

user_name=""
user_id=""
useridDb=""
resultid=""
resultname=""
idUser=""
if os.environ.has_key("HTTP_COOKIE"):
    C= Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE",""))
    if C.has_key("usernameLogin"):
        user_name= C['usernameLogin'].value
        print user_name

form= cgi.FieldStorage()
cgitb.enable()

#Open connection
conn= sqlite3.connect("manager.db")


page1head= """

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Excursions</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/page1.css/' />
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/suggestions.js/"> </script>

</head><body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Field Note Manager</h1>
            <p class="description">Observe...Record...Save!</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Content Section -->
        <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Main Content Section -->
            <div id="content">

                <h2>Excursions</h2>


                    <table CELLPADDING="10" ><tr><th> <strong> Location </strong> </th><th> <strong> Date </strong> </th> <th> Time </th></tr>"""

page2head="""</table>


            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Logout Section -->
        <div id="navigation">

             <input type="hidden" name="greeting"/>
                         <form action="http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/logout.py">
             <p><input type="submit" name="logoutBtn" value="Logout" /> </p>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- Extra Section for Queries -->
        <div id="extra">
            <h2>Quick Links</h2>            


            <dl> <dd><a href="http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/query.py"/>Query the Database</a> </dd></dl>
            <dl> <dd><a href="http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/addFieldNote.py"/>Add Field Note</a> </dd></dl>


        </div>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Copyright  42578647, 2012</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
"""

page1foot= """

</body>
</html>
"""


print "Content_type: text/html\n\n"
print page1head

#print excursion details
cur=conn.cursor()
resultid= cur.execute("SELECT userid FROM login WHERE username=?",[user_name])
cur.fetchone()
for data in resultid:
    idUser= int(data)
resultname= cur.execute("""SELECT location,excurDate,excurTime FROM excursion WHERE user=?""",[idUser])
cur.fetchall()
for record in resultname:
    print"<tr><td>",record[0],"</td><td>",record[1],"</td><td>",record[2],"</td></tr>"
print page2head
print page1foot
```

It prints the page, but no queries are generated. Is it because the cookie has not been retrieved and parsed or is there some problem with the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. The cookies had not been set before the header in the previous validate.py